# On the success or failure of an experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test, pre-post-comparison

Recently I've been asked this question and I wasn't really able to give a solid answer from a statistical standpoint. I hope someone can help me :)

---

**Statement**

Let's say that in a given region, in a given timeframe, $x_1$ car accidents are reported. As a result, the government decides to take action, e.g. by organizing a campaign that promotes the use of seatbelts.

After the campaign, the number of car accidents recorded in the same region, during a similar timeframe is now $x_2$.

The government now asks me whether the campaign should be considered successful or not.

Can I give an answer with the information at hand? If I can, which should it be? If I cannot, which pieces of information I miss here (and I should ask for)?

---

**My reasoning**

I'd say that I would need to know the size of the two experiments, e.g the number of cars that travelled through the region during the two timeframes, or a rough estimate at least. Someone suggested that I should ask for the standard deviation, but it doesn't seem right to me.

If I knew the sizes, say $n_1$ and $n_2$, I could compute the two proportions $\hat{p}_1 = x_1/n_1$ and $\hat{p}_2 = x_2/n_2$. Still, I'd feel that checking that $\hat{p}_1 < \hat{p}_2$ only would not be enough.

Does it make sense to use a z-test for proportions here?
In that case I would use
$$
Z = \dfrac{\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}_1(1-\hat{p}_1)}{n_1}+\dfrac{\hat{p}_2(1-\hat{p}_2)}{n_2}}}
$$
and see where Z sits on the normal distribution.

Is there something else I could do/check to make a more solid statement about the success/failure of the campaign?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't know what would have happened to the accident rate in the absence of the government campaign. It may have gone up, down, or remained relatively unchanged - lots of variables change through time. This uncertainty about the counterfactual is why [causality](/questions/tagged/causality) is often hard to infer.

This is where it is helpful to have additional data from places where the campaign did *not* take place (at both time points, before and after), and use that as a basis for comparison. This allows you to analyse what is called [difference-in-difference](/questions/tagged/difference-in-difference)s. These experimental designs are sometimes called BACI designs (for Before-After-Control-Impact) in fields such as ecology.

Comment: This is the key detail that's swept under the rug by the simple yet critically important statement that it is a "similar timeframe". This sort of suggests there's no meaningful difference between timeframes other than the government intervention, but in practice that will rarely be the case.

Comment: Thanks you all. Very interesting insights! 
It's clear that I am not an expert and we're talking about an oversimplified toy-example. "similar timeframe" is simply to say that we expect $n_1$ and $n_2$ to be roughly the same, although it seems it doesn't make much of a difference.
Assuming the accident rate in the absence of the government campaing remained relatively unchanged, would you use the z-test for proportions? Is it a sound test?